# VBA use right() on range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put the last 4 characters of a table column into an array and dump to column L. I'm using array because it's faster:

```
Dim arrCard() As String
.Range("TableExport[CARD]").NumberFormat = "@"
arrCard = Right(.Range("TableExport[CARD]").Text, 4)
.Range("L2:L10000") = arrCard
```

Then it says

> type mismatch

which doesn't make sens, as CARD column is already text. Does that mean that I cannot use Right() on a range? But I do see a lot of examples use this method (except they do not apply on table columns)

I also tried:

```
Dim arrCard() As Variant
Dim cardnum As Integer
.Range("TableExport[CARD]").NumberFormat = "@"
arrCard = Right(.Range("TableExport[CARD]").Text, 4)
.Range("L2:L10000") = arrCard
```

Then it complains about Type Mismatch on the 4th line. TBH I don't get it, it doesn't seem to be a hell amount of requirement.

Comment: What's the cell value? If it's a cell error, then it's not a string and can't be converted to one.

Comment: Thanks, The cell value is of Text type after the conversion by .NumberFormat = "@"

Comment: NumberFormat won't make a cell error turn into a string; use `IsError` to validate your values. Also, how many cells are in `.Range("TableExport[CARD]")`? If the answer is anything other than 1, then you're working with an array, not a string. `Right` wants a string, not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use RIGHT on a range and need to use it on the specific elements.
Also, because you're setting the array equal to a range it will be a two dimensional array which is why `arrCard(cardnum)` wouldn't work and you have to use `arrCard(cardnum,1)`.

```
Dim arrCard As Variant
Dim cardnum As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Range("CARD").NumberFormat = "@"
    arrCard = .Range("CARD").Value
    For cardnum = LBound(arrCard, 1) To UBound(arrCard, 1)
        arrCard(cardnum, 1) = Right(arrCard(cardnum, 1), 4)
    Next cardnum
    .Range("L2:L10000") = arrCard
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, I had no idea that it would become a two dim array. Really helpful!